# how to get nth record without using index from table?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my interview question.

EX:Table has 100 records and 20 records has been deleted in between Now i want to get 95 record.

When i replayed to this answer like

select * from table name where id = 95;

He said it was wrong and said don't use indexing.

Is it something possible like that??

If yes How to write query?
Note:
1)should not use index

Comment: `ORDER BY id OFFSET 95 LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: `"Table has 100 records and 20 records has been deleted"` - Wouldn't this mean that the table now has only 80 records?  So there is no "95th" record?  The interview question itself is unclear.  There's no definition of what the "95th" record is or what criteria are being used to find it.  It sounds like the person conducting the interview doesn't understand the question either.

Comment: @Strawberry Plz Answer in detail it may be even helpful to other's Even i can accept your answer.Thank you

Comment: @David May be you are true.

Comment: @SatishKilari: In that case, "What is the arbitrary answer someone was looking for to a question they didn't understand?" isn't something we can effectively answer here.  Ask the interviewer what they were looking for.

Comment: `OFFSET 94 LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @David Even i asked him for answer.He kept quit.

Comment: @SatishKilari: We're not more effective at reading your interviewer's mind than you are.  The question he asked is incomplete, there is no "right" answer.  "The 95th record" is entirely arbitrary and would change with the ordering of the results.  Select just about any record and there likely exists a sort order in which it would be the 95th record.

Comment: I would have understand it as : The table now have 100 records but in the past, 20 record have been deleted. So that the id index doesn't increase continuously.

Comment: The question is quite ambigous

Answer (score 1):

`'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'id' OFFSET 95 LIMIT 1'` was probably the answer the interviewer was waiting for.

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause, OFFSET and LIMIT are fairly meaningless.

Comment: OFFSET can only be used with an ORDER BY clause.